# make new page without standard button

Tags: php, jquery, css

i want program `chatroom` and private chat between user .
in click on each user name in chat sidebar open new page like `chatbox` with beautiful layer and without standard button like close or minimize .

example : [pic](http://up.vatandownload.com/images/dq2vod8v1dn2vd1hse9e.jpg)

***Code***

```
 <a href="javavoid()" onclick="privatechat()">User1</a>
 <a href="javavoid()" onclick="privatechat()">User2</a>
 <a href="javavoid()" onclick="privatechat()">User3</a>
```

how i can design this page and open this page when click on name?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: what is your question? what is onclick? how create chat system? how create box with css?

Comment: @Trikks means "if we are going to help you, you need to at least make an effort to have first helped yourself." What attempt has been made to accomplish your goal? What types of things have you tried to resolve your question?

Comment: It seems as though he wants to know how to open a new div instead of another window

Comment: i want know how i cam design this page like pic and when click on user show this page.

Comment: Behzad, you should probably have basic developer skills before asking a question at Stackoverflow. There are plenty of tutorials and sites helping you with the absolute basics of web design and development.

Comment: i only want how can design page like this pic or whats name of this page for search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well If I understand you correctly you are indeed looking to create a web-based chat application (like the Facebook chat), am I right?

We won't be able to provide code for you, that is your job, but instead I could give you a resource to a tutorial that you mind find useful.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application/

Or you might find any useful script here http://php.resourceindex.com/Complete_Scripts/Chat/

Best luck to you!